# Redux-observable: failed jest test for epic

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, redux-observable

I followed the steps from [documentation](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html) to test epic.

```
...
store.dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER });

expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([
   { type: FETCH_USER },
   { type: FETCH_USER_FULFILLED, payload }
]);
...
```

But I get failed because second action is been received some later like following.

```
Test failed
    Expected value to equal:
      [{"type": "FETCH_USER"}, {"type": "FETCH_USER_FULFILLED", "payload": [some]}]
    Received:
      [{"type": "FETCH_USER"}]

    Difference:

    - Expected
    + Received

    @@ -1,20 +1,5 @@
     Array [
       Object {"type": "FETCH_USER"},
       Object {"type": "FETCH_USER_FULFILLED", "payload": [some]} ] // this is what should be.
```

So I think I should know when the dispatch is finished or some like that.
How can I solve this?

I used fetch() and Rx.Observable.fromPromise instead of ajax.getJSON()

Here is my epic.

```
const fetchUserEpic = (action$) =>
  action$
    .ofType(FETCH_USER)
    .mergeMap(() => {
      return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(api.fetchUser())
        .map((users) => ({
          type: FETCH_USER_FULFILLED,
          payload: { users }
        }))
        .catch((error) => Rx.Observable.of({
          type: FETCH_USER_ERROR,
          payload: { error }
        }))
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_CANCELLED))
    })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that promises always resolve on the [next microtask](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/) so your `api.fetchUser()` isn't emitting synchronously.

You'll need to either mock it out, use something like `Promise.resolve().then(() => expect(store.getActions).toEqual(...)` to wait until the next microtask, or you can experiment with testing your epics *directly* without using redux.

```
it('Epics with the appropriate input and output of actions', (done) => {
  const action$ = ActionsObservable.of({ type: 'SOMETHING' });

  somethingEpic(action$, store)
    .toArray() // collects everything in an array until our epic completes
    .subscribe(actions => {
      expect(actions).to.deep.equal([
        { type: 'SOMETHING_FULFILLED' }// whatever actions
      ]);

      done();
    });
});
```

This will be our preferred testing story in the docs when I (or someone else) has time to write them up. So instead of using redux and the middleware in your tests, we just call the epic function directly with our own mocks. Much easier and cleaner.

With that approach, we can leverage the new dependency injection feature of redux-observable: https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/InjectingDependenciesIntoEpics.html

---

```
import { createEpicMiddleware, combineEpics } from 'redux-observable';
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax';
import rootEpic from './somewhere';

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic, {
  dependencies: { getJSON: ajax.getJSON }
});
```

---

```
// Notice the third argument is our injected dependencies!
const fetchUserEpic = (action$, store, { getJSON }) =>
  action$.ofType('FETCH_USER')
    .mergeMap(() =>
      getJSON(`/api/users/${payload}`)
        .map(response => ({
          type: 'FETCH_USER_FULFILLED',
          payload: response
        }))
    );
```

---

```
import { ActionsObservable } from 'redux-observable';
import { fetchUserEpic } from './somewhere/fetchUserEpic';

const mockResponse = { name: 'Bilbo Baggins' };
const action$ = ActionsObservable.of({ type: 'FETCH_USERS_REQUESTED' });
const store = null; // not needed for this epic
const dependencies = {
  getJSON: url => Observable.of(mockResponse)
};

// Adapt this example to your test framework and specific use cases
fetchUserEpic(action$, store, dependencies)
  .toArray() // buffers all emitted actions until your Epic naturally completes()
  .subscribe(actions => {
    assertDeepEqual(actions, [{
      type: 'FETCH_USER_FULFILLED',
      payload: mockResponse
    }]);
  });
```

Comment: I see the solution is correct. I get "TypeError: Cannot read property '_location' of null", though it is outside of the problem.

Comment: I was banging my head on this for a few hours... tried this and got "...toArray is not a function" error.

Comment: Yeah, it's always up to the RxJS user to decide how they want to import operators.

Comment: Still having problems... the epic with Observable.ajax returns DOMException InvalidAccessError. I'm using Jest and Nock. Seems it is not mocking correctly...

Comment: The problem is not in the ajax call. Any observable executing asynchronously makes it timeout. the call to `done` never happens.

Comment: got it.. if expect is not met then `done` doesn't get called. problems is output of failing tests isn't really correct.

Comment: I was an issue on Jest repo: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1873

Comment: Ah, this is simple and makes a lot of sense. One question I have is where does .toArray() come from? Is that an RxJS thing or a redux-observable thing?

Comment: @Anselan rxjs. redux-observable currently only provides `ofType`, every other operator is rxjs and needs to be imported

Comment: @jayphelps It really helps. I am following this approach to create unit tests, but I have created wrapper method for ajax calls. How I can inject dependencies for my wrapper methods?

Comment: You are missing `.pipe()` after epic call. Means it should be `epicCall.pipe(toArray())`

Answer (score 0):

First, use [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) instead of Observable.ajax for nock support, like this

```
const fetchSomeData = (api: string, params: FetchDataParams) => {
const request = fetch(`${api}?${stringify(params)}`)
  .then(res => res.json());
  return Observable.from(request);
};
```

So my epic is:

```
const fetchDataEpic: Epic<GateAction, ImGateState> = action$ =>
  action$
    .ofType(FETCH_MODEL)
    .mergeMap((action: FetchModel) =>
      fetchDynamicData(action.url, action.params)
        .map((payload: FetchedData) => fetchModelSucc(payload.data))
        .catch(error => Observable.of(
          fetchModelFail(error)
      )));
```

Then, you may need an interval to decide when to finish the test.

```
describe("epics", () => {
  let store: MockStore<{}>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    nock.cleanAll();
    epicMiddleware.replaceEpic(epic);
  });
  it("fetch data model succ", () => {
    const payload = {
      code: 0,
      data: someData,
      header: {},
      msg: "ok"
    };
    const params = {
      data1: 100,
      data2: "4"
    };
    const mock = nock("https://test.com")
      .get("/test")
      .query(params)
      .reply(200, payload);
    const go = new Promise((resolve) => {
      store.dispatch({
        type: FETCH_MODEL,
        url: "https://test.com/test",
        params
      });
      let interval: number;
      interval = window.setInterval(() => {
        if (mock.isDone()) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          resolve(store.getActions());
        }
      }, 20);
    });
    return expect(go).resolves.toEqual([
      {
        type: FETCH_MODEL,
        url: "https://test.com/assignment",
        params
      },
      {
        type: FETCH_MODEL_SUCC,
        data: somData
      }
    ]);
  });
});
```

enjoy it :)